# Project Euler 12 on Python

Tags: python

So I'm solving **Problem 12** of **Project Euler** in Python. There's the task:

> The sequence of triangle numbers is generated by adding the natural
> numbers. So the 7th triangle number would be **1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 +
> 7 = 28**. The first ten terms would be:
>
> **1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55, ...**
>
> Let us list the factors of the first seven triangle numbers:
>
> **1: 1**
>   **3: 1,3**
>   **6: 1,2,3,6**
>
> **10: 1,2,5,10**
>
> **15: 1,3,5,15**
>
> **21: 1,3,7,21**
>
> **28: 1,2,4,7,14,28**
>  
>  We can see that 28 is the *first triangle number* to have over *five divisors*.
>
> What is the value of the *first triangle number* to have over *five
> hundred divisors?*

I made 2 functions: first will generate triangle numbers infinitely:

```
def triangle_number(n_th_triangle, triangle_sum_number, triangle):
    while True:
        n_th_triangle += 1

        while triangle_sum_number < n_th_triangle:
            triangle_sum_number += 1

            triangle += triangle_sum_number

        print(triangle)

triangle_number(0, 0, 0)
```

second one will count, how many divisors has the given number:

```
def divisor_number(divisor, divisor_number, number):
    while divisor < number:
        divisor += 1

        if number % divisor == 0:
            divisor_number += 1

    print(number)
    print(divisor_number)

divisor_number(0, 0, *number*)
```

How to slap them together ? So that will be the solution of the *12 th problem on Project Euler*.

**Thanks!**

Comment: Making the first function `yield triangle` instead of printing it would be a good start.

Comment: I wonder how long your program will run once it's ready.

Comment: Also, testing all possible divisors will be too slow. You could first get the first few thousand prime numbers, then get the prime factors of a number, then combine those to the actual divisors.

Comment: Trincot...but what's the difference?

Comment: You mean: does it matter? Well yes, if you want to get the answer still in 2020...

Comment: Since you're starting out programming: the comment and answer about using `yield` are fine suggestions, but generator functions (which is what `yield` gives you) are a moderately advanced programming technique. If you've not yet mastered using normal functions, I would focus on those instead for the time being.

Comment: Note the the `n`-th triangular number is `n*(n+1)//2`.  taking advantage of this, the prime factors are the union of the prime factors of `n` and `n+1`, with one factor of `2` removed.  From the prime factors (with counts), you can determine the total number of factors.  This should speed things up significantly.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should return these values rather than print them.

As others have mentioned, using the `yield` keyword will allow you to return values to the caller without suspending function execution and deleting everything you already computed from the stack. [Here](https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/) is a pretty good tutorial on using generators in python.

Then, once you implement triangle_number() as a generator, you could have a simple loop such as the following:

```
tri_gen = triangle_number()
while(divisor_number(num)) <= 500:
    num = next(tri_gen)
```

Comment: For generating a sequence of triangle numbers, "functions that run infinitely" are perfectly the right tool in Python. Those are called "generator functions" and are evaluated lazily using `yield` and `next`. Getting just the nth triangle number is either much slower or more complicated.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this functionality in Python, good point. Editing my answer now.

Answer (score 1):

Some pointers:

- you should `yield` the next triangle number instead of just printing it
- you do not have to declare all internal variables as parameters
- do not test *all* possible divisors, this will be *much* too slow

Instead, you can try the following:

- calculate the first few thousand prime numbers using [an efficient algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)
- use those to calculate the prime factorization of the number, e.g. `[2, 5, 5]` for `50`; use divide an conquer and memoization to speed this up <sup>1</sup>
- finally, use the prime factorization to efficiently calculate the total number of divisors

Just for perspective, the result is a >> 10k-th triangle number and is somewhere around 75M.

<sup>1)</sup> As noted [in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62758826/project-euler-12-on-python/62759018?noredirect=1#comment110984132_62758826) you can use the fact that `sum(1..n)`, and thus the n-th triangle number, is `n(n+1)/2` and use that to find the prime factorization (and thus the divisors) much easier.